# Can one use a conventional microphone as an underground acoustic sensor?

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor

I need an acoustic sensor I can bury to monitor the immediate area acoustically for footsteps. Is it possible to simply bury a microphone and call it a day, or would a more specialized underground acoustic sensor be necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You have already asked a very similar question, and I'll give you the same answer. The common method of detecting footsteps using a detector buried in soil is a **seismic sensor cable**.

The frequencies of interest for footsteps are much lower than the frequencies picked up by a microphone. The energy you want to detect is not really acoustic, it is seismic. I can assure that if it was as easy as just burying a microphone we would have already done it.

Comment: A microphone diaphragm is vibrated by sound frequencies through the air. When buried there probably is no air to cause the diaphragm to vibrate.